# How to execute “reboot recovery” in recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, reboot

I need to run `"reboot recovery"` while in Android recovery mode without using PC.

My recovery didn't accept recovery parameter `"recovery"`.

`adb reboot recovery` - reboots recovery to recovery.

`rom shell "reboot recovery"` - just reboot to system.

Trying to push normal reboot to `/tmp` and run it, but `sh` says that it couldn't find `/tmp/reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

TWRP make it like below, maybe this can help

```
case rb_recovery:
            check_and_run_script("/sbin/rebootrecovery.sh", "reboot recovery");
```

[GitHub ref](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/blob/d63c7643fd7749de1723ce1adc5907fed1c1a11c/twrp-functions.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Press the power off button and the volume down button at the same time before turning it on. The system will then enter the device reset mode.

Comment: Welcome to an international Q&A site, Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Sorry, but this site has [English-only policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/241919). Consider [edit]ing and translating it to English. I translated it this time, but please use English for future communication, thanks.